# Azure WVD RDS - ARM Version

Tags: azure, windows-10, remoteapp, wvd

I have an interesting issue, whereby my predecessor created an RDS tenant, I was unable to see this from the azure portal, but upon reading up. I discovered that the tenant was created in the ARM Version and that I was only able to access this through powershell. I have given myself access to tenant as an owner, but I have the following issues.

1. Am I able to recover the tenant and access it however, in the portal as nothing is showing, no resourcegroup, hostpools or appgroups.
2. When I try to add a remote app, it fails and I am unable to find out if I am using the correct URL for the remote app, if someone could point me a way to find the correct URL, that would be great.

Comment: Did you check this out - sounds like your predecessor created a classic deployment of WVD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/virtual-desktop-fall-2019/tenant-setup-azure-active-directory ? So, they must have followed these steps, so you can try to see if these (similar steps work for you).

Comment: This is exactly where I am, I don't want to recreate the tenant as it's live and working, but I am unable to edit/find any information beyond what powershell is able to show me.

Comment: Ok, then you should be able to do Get-RdsTenant and it should return the tenants that were already created. Then, Get-RdsHostPool, Get-RdsSessionHost and everything else here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/windows-virtual-desktop/overview

Comment: I have done all of this, as suggested, I want to be able to migrate the existing environment so that I can see it in the portal, secondly, if possible I want to confirm the URL for remote apps and check the permissions, these options are not available through powershell.

Answer (score 0):

The ARM version is accessible through the web portal in Azure from the WBD Blade, are you meaning it was created with classic WVD? Powershell or creating a management instance is the only way to manage this.

Some information about ARM - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/getting-started-windows-virtual-desktop-arm-based-azure-portal/ba-p/1374466